# Java: TaskExecutor for Asynchronous Database Writes?

Tags: java, database, asynchronous, nio

I'm thinking of using Java's TaskExecutor to fire off asynchronous database writes. Understandably threads don't come for free, but assuming I'm using a fixed threadpool size of say 5-10, how is this a bad idea?

Our application reads from a very large file using a buffer and flushes this information to a database after performing some data manipulation. Using asynchronous writes seems ideal here so that we can continue working on the file. What am I missing? Why doesn't every application use asynchronous writes?

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't every application use asynchronous writes?

It's often necessary/usefull/easier to deal with a write failure in a synchronous manner.

Comment: What are some good ways to deal with write failures when writing data to the database asynchronously. I'm also writing to the cache at run time and then persisting data to the database asynchronously. An approach that I though of was to "somehow" persist the task that are queued in the ThreadPoolExecutor. Does this make sense? Is there a better/easier approach?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure a threadpool is even necessary. I would consider using a dedicated databaseWriter thread which does all writing and error handling for you. Something like:

```
 public class AsyncDatabaseWriter implements Runnable {
     private LinkedBlockingQueue<Data> queue = ....
     private volatile boolean terminate = false;

     public void run() {
         while(!terminate) {
            Data data = queue.take();
            // write to database
         }
     }
     public void ScheduleWrite(Data data) {
         queue.add(data);
     }
 }
```

I personally fancy the style of using a `Proxy` for threading out operations which might take a long time. I'm not saying this approach is better than using executors in any way, just adding it as an alternative.

Comment: When using a proxy is there any good way to add persistence to the queue?

Answer (score 2):

Idea is not bad at all. Actually I just tried it yesterday because I needed to create a copy of online database which has 5 different categories with like 60000 items each.

By moving parse/save operation of each category into the parallel tasks and partitioning each category import into smaller batches run in parallel I reduced the total import time from several hours (estimated) to 26 minutes. Along the way I found good piece of code for splitting the collection: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaAlgorithmsPartitionCollection/article.html

I used ThreadPoolTaskExecutor to run tasks. Your tasks are just simple implementation of Callable interface.

Answer (score -2):

why doesn't every application use asynchronous writes? - erm because every application does a different thing.

can you believe some applications don't even use a database OMG!!!!!!!!!

seriously though, given as you don't say what your failure strategies are - sounds like it could be reasonable. What happens if the write fails? or the db does away somehow

some databases - like sybase - have (or at least had) a thing where they really don't like multiple writers to a single table - all the writers ended up blocking each other - so maybe it wont actually make much difference...