# Java - How to save objects to database asynchronously?

Tags: java, database, asynchronous, persistence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: TaskExecutor for Asynchronous Database Writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288759/java-taskexecutor-for-asynchronous-database-writes)

I have a Map of data objects in memory that I need to be able to read and write to very quickly. I would like these objects to be persistent across process restarts so I'd like to have them stored in a DB.

Since I'd rather not have any DB inserts or updates slow down my running time, I'd like to have them done immediately in memory and later, asynchronously to the DB. (It's even acceptable to me if the process crashes and a little bit of data is lost.)

Is there a Java tool (preferably open source) that has this ability "out of the box"? Can this easily be done with Hibernate?

Comment: You can use TaskExecutor to persist in DB in an async manner. Infact found something better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5288831/231917 Looks like a duplicate question.

Comment: Come to think of it - not really duplicate. I'm asking "how". She/He's asking "why" and mentions just one solution. Would rather keep my question open until I get more options for "how".

Comment: What kind of database you need? Is it possible to use a NoSQL database? If that's okay, consider using MongoDB, it provides a fire and forget mechanism for executing queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have also stated in my comment, if you need async writes and do not want to use hibernate or ehcache:

1. **Runnable**: The only way to achieve async processing in Java will be via simple class which extends Runnable:

   ```
   public class AsyncDatabaseWriter implements Runnable {
        private LinkedBlockingQueue<Data> queue = ....
        private volatile boolean terminate = false;
        public void run() {
            while(!terminate) {
               Data data = queue.take();
               // write to database
            }
        }
        public void ScheduleWrite(Data data) {
            queue.add(data);
        }
    }
   ```

   Also stated here: [Java: TaskExecutor for Asynchronous Database Writes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288759/java-taskexecutor-for-asynchronous-database-writes)
2. **Distributed workers**: If you want to introduce more moving parts in your system, then you can try java alternative of distributed task queue like [celery](http://celeryproject.org/): [hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/) or [octobot](https://github.com/cscotta/Octobot). This will need a messaging tier in between which will act as a queue and the workers will do the task of writing to DB for you. This looks likes an overkill, but again depends on your use case and the scale at which you want to use your app.
   I did something very similar where I had a use case to write to DB in an async manner, so I went with celery (python). Sample implementation can be found here: [artemis](https://github.com/utkarsh2012/artemis)

Comment: In the AsyncDatabaseWriter, is there any good way of persisting the tasks? i.e., in case of a failure in the server or a thread dying for some reason, some other server should pick up the task. I thought the distributed workers method would be overkill for this. Is that the best way to go ahead though?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using write behind caching, e.g. in [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/recipes/writebehind):

> [...] writing data into the cache, instead of writing the data into database at the same time, the write-behind cache saves the changed data into a queue and lets a backend thread to do the writing later. Therefore, the cache-write process can proceed without waiting for the database-write and, thus, be finished much faster. Any data that has been changed can be persisted into database eventually. In the mean time, any read from cache will still get the latest data.

Unfortunately I don't know how and if write behind integrates with Hibernate (don't think so).

Comment: `EhCache` does integrate with `hibernate`. I am using it in a project.

Comment: @jidma: I know Hibernate second level cache integrates very well with EhCache. I meant if write behind can integrate with Hibernate. I'll correct my answer

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Definitely hibernate is not using write behind caching, see: "But H2LC is not Write-Behind caching." from: http://tusharkhairnar.blogspot.ro/2009/06/terracottas-hibernate-integration.html

Comment: Thanks everyone. Dan, so Hibernate definitely does not provide write behind functionality by itself?

Comment: Also, isn't Ehcache a bit of an overkill considering I'm not in a distributed environment? (single process)

Answer (score 1):

In hibernate you choose when you want to persist data in the database, you work mainly with `proxy` objects (that you can keep and manipulate in memory) and you call `save` method whenever you want to insert or update in the database.

Comment: Thank you jidma. Any functionality in Hibernate (or through a plug-in) that will do the save async for me? I'd much rather have an established piece of code do the scheduling and syncing that do it myself.

Comment: when do you want to actually persist data ? is it triggered by some process ?

Comment: I'd like to persist every X minutes. Just so I have the objects "backed up" to the DB. If my process restarts (which it does once a day) I can restore from the "back up" at init()

Comment: well not sure that hibernate does that out of the box, you'll need to trigger your update every X minutes by yourself.